# SQLite iOS Insert data

Tags: ios, sqlite, insert

Im trying to insert just one name to my sqlite file. im using this code but it's not working :/

```
-(void)InsertRecords:(NSMutableString *) txt{
    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "INSERT INTO myMovies (movieName)  VALUES(?) ";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        else
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [txt UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    }
    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))

        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}
```

Comment: @adum The error is : Assertion failure in -[MyDvDsList InsertRecords:], /Users/.../MyDvDsList.m:52
2012-10-25 02:00:54.916 MyDvDs[28287:14003] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating add statement. 'out of memory''

Comment: When you get the "out of memory" error, that confusingly actually means that the `sqlite3` pointer for the the `database` is `NULL` (generally symptomatic of failure to properly open the database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok finally I made it ! this is the code that I used for everyone who need it :

```
-(void)InsertRecords:(NSMutableString *)txt{

    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"movieData.sqlite"];
    const char *dbpath = [dbPath UTF8String];
    sqlite3 *contactDB;

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    NSLog(@"%@",dbPath);
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO myMovies (movieName) VALUES (\"%@\")", txt];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [txt UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. First, you are inserting data into the database in the bundle, which is read only. Use the Documents folder instead. Second, you are building SQL using `stringWithFormat`, but if the value contained a quotation mark, the SQL will fail. Always use `?` placeholders and `sqlite3_bind_XXX` with string values in SQL statements. Third, I'd generally suggest logging `sqlite3_errmsg` in the `else` clause so that if it failed, you'll know why. Fourth, I'd advise against opening and closing the database every time. Open the database when app starts, and close it upon termination.

Comment: this is open to SQL injection attack

Answer (score 2):

pass your query to this method and try,

```
-(void)Insertdata:(NSString*)query{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourDBName.sql"];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",query];

        char *errmsg=nil;

        if(sqlite3_exec(db, [querySQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errmsg)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
           NSLog(@".. Row Added ..");
        }
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An "out of memory" error from sqlite typically means the database handle you are using hasn't been opened yet. Make sure you are calling `sqlite3_open_v2` with the `database` variable shown in the code you posted?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//save our data
- (BOOL) saveEmployee:(Employee *)employee
{
    BOOL success = false;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &mySqliteDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (employee.employeeID > 0) {
            NSLog(@"Exitsing data, Update Please");
            NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE EMPLOYEES set name = '%@', department = '%@', age = '%@' WHERE id = ?",
                                    employee.name,
                                    employee.department,
                                    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", employee.age]];

            const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(mySqliteDB, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL );
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, employee.employeeID);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                success = true;
            }

        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"New data, Insert Please");
            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (name, department, age) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                                   employee.name,
                                   employee.department,
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", employee.age]];

            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(mySqliteDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                success = true;
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(mySqliteDB);

    }

    return success;
}
```