# issue during insert data by using sqlite3 in to db iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I have an issue where I am trying to insert data from `NSMutableArra`y in to my database. Here is what I have so far:

```
- (void)insertList:(NSString*) strListName ArrayOfData:(NSMutableArray*) dataArray{
sqlite3 *database = nil;
sqlite3_stmt *addStmt = nil;

NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"customlists.sqlite"];
if(sqlite3_open([defaultDBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.count; i++)
    {
        PageData *pageDta = [PageData new];
        pageDta = [dataArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if(addStmt == nil) {
            const char *sql = "insert into NewList(ListName, PageName, PageNumber, id) Values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [strListName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [pageDta.strNamebyFilter UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [pageDta.strPageNuber UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 4, i);

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        else
            //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
            sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

        //Reset the add statement.
        sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error while opening database '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

But after calling this function, the database is empty. Could someone help me to find the cause of this issue and potential remedies?

Comment: there is so much code to start thinking whats the problem is... maybe you can debug it or reduce the problem to some part of the code. If you paste this code in stackoverflow waiting for an answer, you will not get so much help... good luck!

Comment: Do you have any output Log ? or just nothing happens ? !

Comment: actually function runs successfully with no error, so there is nothing to debug.

Comment: the debug tool is not only used when you found an error, most of the time it will be helpful if you dont know what is happening...

Comment: take a look at my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060166/sqlite-ios-insert-data , hope it helps :)

Comment: Well, all sql functions returns successful values, maybe I am doing something wrong in order call of this function or maybe calling wrong functions. I am new in iOS development and SQLite3.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is simple - you are trying to write to a database in the app's bundle. This isn't allowed. An app's bundle is read-only on a real device (though it is writable in the simulator). The proper thing to do is copy the database from the resource bundle to a writable area of the app's sandbox the first time the app runs. Then every use of the database is done with the copy.

It would also be cleaner to prepare the statement before the `for` loop. No need to keep checking if it has been setup every loop iteration.

You make a call to `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid` but don't do anything with the value. What's the point?

You never finalize the statement after the loop is complete. You need to do that.

And you don't close the database when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

change this line :

```
const char *sql = "insert into NewList(ListName, PageName, PageNumber, id) Values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

to :

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"NSString stringWithFormat: "INSERT INTO  NewList(ListName, PageName, PageNumber, id) VALUES(\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")" ,strListName, pageDta.strNamebyFilter, pageDta.strPageNuber, addStmt];

const char *sql = [insertSQL UTF8String];
```

Comment: I've got next error:[49304:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[DBManager insertNewList:ArrayOfData:], /Users/admin/Documents/DBManager.m:85

Comment: This is the worse possible way to create a query string. Never use a string format for this.

Comment: could you please provide better way?

Comment: @Roman You are already doing it the right way. Use the ? in the query then binding the values to the statement.

Comment: I should add why Rudi's answer is bad. First off, text values need to be in single quotes, not double quotes. Also, what happens when one of the string values contains a quote? This is how SQL injection security holes are made. By using a query string with a question mark for each value and calling `sqlite3_bind_xxx`, the library takes care of any quoting and escaping needed. It eliminates a whole set of possible errors and security issues.

Comment: Thanks maddy , I tried your solution before but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Hopefully it works for you Roman. Cheers

Comment: @Rudi What doesn't work for you? Using `sqlite3_bind_xxx`? If didn't work then you obviously did something wrong because that's how most people do it (the one's that aren't, should be).

Answer (score -1):

I've rewrite function to:

```
 if(sqlite3_open([defaultDBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.count; i++)
    {
        PageData *pageDta = [PageData new];
        pageDta = [dataArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if(addStmt == nil) {
            const char *sql = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO NewList (ListName, PageName, PageNumber) values('%@', '%@', '%@')",strListName,pageDta.strNamebyFilter, pageDta.strPageNuber] UTF8String];

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [strListName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [pageDta.strNamebyFilter UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [pageDta.strPageNuber UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        //Reset the add statement.
        sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error while opening database '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

but result is the same :(

Comment: You should have updated your question with this information instead of posting it as an answer. It appears you ignored my primary statement - you can't write to a database in the resource bundle. You didn't move the prepare statement. Your query string is still incorrect. You are trying to call `sqlite3_bind_text` on a query that doesn't contain any ? characters in it. Your original query string was correct. DON'T use stringWithFormat to create a query.