# Saving data in sqlite issue in objective c

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have some values in labels and i'm trying to store it in my database but when i hit save button it isn't save and log a message failed to save. The database is properly made but data is not storing. My code for saving data is this,

```
- (IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender {

sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO data (ID, ALERT, XREF,TEXT,GRAPHIC,PROMPT,VOICE) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")", _lblID.text, _lblAlert.text, _lblxref.text,_lbltext.text, _lblgraphic.text, _lblprompt.text,_lblvoice.text];
    NSLog(@"DDD %@",insertSQL);

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        _lblstatus.text = @"Contact added";

    } else {
        _lblstatus.text = @"Failed to add contact";
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you define contactDB inside your method? 
Also, you should use proper table names in SQLite. Table name `data` in SQL query seems inappropriate.

Refer answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13085667/4988884

Comment: followed ur link but not working again. @MohnishHirudkar

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
    _lblstatus.text = @"Contact added";
} else {
     NSLog(@"prepare failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
    _lblstatus.text = @"Failed to add contact";
}
```

**1. Replace this snippet in your code to print error message. It will help you to find exact issue.**

**2. May be the SQL query which your forming is syntactically wrong.**

Comment: i have searched a lot most of them has written query like this , i have removed the above code as u said but again its not working. @MARTIN

Comment: I'm not getting any error in code , just nslog the error if data is not saved and it shows that error that data is not saved. @MARTIN

Comment: When i create a databse i have NSLog the path and its taking me to the right path and the table is created fine but the issue is values are not saving in the database. @MARTIN